# Php cookie not setting

Tags: php, cookies, setting

Alright I'm totally baffled.

Here's my code:

```
if ($password == $correct_password[0] && !isset($_COOKIE['user'])) {
            setcookie("user", $email, time() + 3600);
            var_dump(isset($_COOKIE['user']));
            echo "!";
        }
```

So it's doing the var_dumps, meaning that the setcookie should called. But the line right after it (checking if it's set) says it's not set!

If anyone could point out the problem it'd be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still didn't find a solid valid answer, but after endless hours of testing it seems like something with the time. If I set the expiration date too close to the real time, maybe it doesn't register or something. It seemed to work when I set the time further, but I'm taking a break before heavy testing again.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$_COOKIE is populated/loaded when the script first starts up, and then is **NOT** updated by PHP again for the life of the script. Setting a cookie via setcookie will only show up in $_COOKIE on the NEXT execution of the script.

This applies to all of the superglobals, except $_SESSION. They're populated/initalized at script startup and then PHP does not ever touch them again. $_SESSION is populated when you call `session_start()` (or sessions are set to auto start), which may be done multiple times within a script's lifetime.

Comment: I've got this scipt `<?php $email = "me@gmail.com"; setcookie("foo", $email, time() + 60); ?>
<html>
<body>
<?php var_dump(isset($_COOKIE['foo'])); ?>
</body>
</html>` and if I keep refreshing the page it still says the cookie isn't set

Answer (score 1):

**PHP is a server-side language.**

That means that it can generate whatever it wants and will then pass it to the client.
And that's it.
There is no back and forward on a single request.

```
1º you instruct the page 'A' to set a cookie
2º client recieves page 'A' and sets the cookie
3º client asks for page 'B' (sending the cookie)
4º server can identify the cookie (only on page 'B')
```

Page here is used as simple way of understanding a server call.
You can request the same page twice for the purpose.

Comment: So I made a simple test page with a cookie set at the beginning and a cookie call in the body. So the page is instructed to set a cookie, it recieves the page and sets the cookie. Later in the page it asks for the cookie... shouldn't it already be set? Or does it set the cookie **after** everything is loaded? However, on consequent refreshes of the page (cookie should have already been completely set) it still says no cookie set.

Comment: Alright here's my test page: `<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if (setcookie("foo", "me.com", time() + 60 * 2)) {
 echo "worked";
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<?php var_dump(isset($_COOKIE['foo'])); ?>
</body>
</html>` After several refreshes it still says the cookie set isn't set, yet it's echoing that it succesfully set the cookie! What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you use setcookie() it will save its value the **next** time that the HTML is loaded. If you want to see the vardump with the value you **just** assigned you will need to use $_COOKIE['cookie_name'] = $value;